# Java how to pass an object as argument from class to another class

Tags: java, object

I have a problem and I can't find an answer to understand clearly how to pass an object as an argument from a class to another class.

Let's say for example

```
class Player{

private String name;
private int tokens;
private Player player;
Private Casino casino;

public Player(){

}

public Player(String name, int tokens){
this.name = name;
this.tokens = tokens;
}

public String getName(){
return name;
}

public int getTokens(){
return tokens;
}

public void joinCasino(){
player = new Player(getName(), getTokens());
casino = new Casino();
casino.addPlayer(player);
}
```

so basically i receive a name and tokens amount in the constructor and im trying to pass these "attributes" in an object "player".

```
class Casino{

public void addPlayer(Player player){
}
```

I don't know how to pass this player object and use the "name" and "tokens" in the class casino.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

> `casino.addPlayer(player);`

You're doing it. That is 'passing the player object' to the `addPlayer` method of your casino object.

> and use the "name" and "tokens" in the class casino.

You've got the object reference, so, just `player.getName()`:

```
public void addPlayer(Player player) {
  String x = player.getName();
  System.out.println(x);

  // or in one line:
  System.out.println(player.getName());
}
```